# SQL server encryption

Tags: sql-server, security, encryption, sql-server-2019, enterprise-edition

i am using SQL server enterprise edition V.2019

i need to encrypt some columns

i liked IBM Guardium for File and Database Encryption but the cost is too high .

so i found some other solutions

1-  SQL server always encrypted
2-  DbDefence

but it seems i could face a mismatch error after decryption with always encrypted when using varchar  .
and i have no experience with both of them

i need your recommendations kindly , what is the best solutions for security and performance that i can use ?even if it is not mentioned here !

thanks

Comment: I suggest you add another tag with the SQL Server version.
Did you read [Encrypt a Column of Data] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: "what is the best solutions for security and performance"  That depends entirely on your requirements.  What attack vectors are you trying to mitigate with encryption?